# dense *-subalgebra that is not an ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Given $A$ is an $C^{*}$-algebra, is there any examples that a dense subalgebra $D$ contained in an twosided, self-adjoint, non-trivial ideal $I$, while $D$ is not an ideal in $A$? In other words, I am looking for examples of dense subalgebra that is not dense ideal in $C^{*}$-algebras.

I know that if we remove "non-trivial" from the conditions, then $\mathbb{C}$ is an example. Since all rational complex numbers form a dense subalgebra, but it is not an ideal.

**Edit**

$D$ is dense in $A$, not in $I$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you mean to ask.

Comment: So you want $D \subseteq I \lhd A$, with $D$ dense in $A$ I believe (I guess with some non-triviality conditions).

Comment: @PStheman Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)\subset C_c(\mathbb R)\lhd C_0(\mathbb R)$$
where $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ denotes the algebra of smooth functions on $\mathbb R$ with compact support, $C_c(\mathbb R)$ denotes the algebra of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ with compact support, and $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is the $C^*$-algebra  of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ that vanish at infinity.